Movie where the stranger licks toes of a girl in a bus
I'm looking for them movie which:

I guess is some stupid comedy, but I remind the scene and I have to know;
is English language movie from late 90';
there is the scene where the girl is traveling with bus over the night and she felt asleep; the stranger who is licking her toes did wake up her


You're after Road Trip.
The actress Amy Smart even discussed that scene in an interview:

IGN Movies: What was it like to do that scene on the bus with Todd?
  [While riding the bus a guy, played by Road Trip director Todd
  Phillips, sneaks up on her and starts licking her toes – much to her
  disgust.]
Amy Smart: He [Todd Phillips] is so funny. And he has a foot fetish.
IGN Movies: Were those your toes or did they have a double?
Amy Smart: No, those are my toes.
IGN Movies: They weren't?
Amy Smart: No, they were. They were. Yeah. That was so - that was just
  like a fun scene that we did, with his wig.

Below is the scene:



